# (Django) Where my method for model management should be in?

Tags: python, django

### Situation

I'm making my website using `Django`. I'm trying to make it structful.

`Django` provides `User` and `Group` in `django.contrib.models`.

In my app `board`, there are `Board` model.

Each `Board` has accessible, readable, commentable, writable permissions for each `Group` of `User`s. This is managed by an extra model, `BoardPermission` which is related by `ManyToManyField(auth.User, through='BoardPermission')` in `Group` model.

So in db, `BoardPermission` has 4 fields: `id`, `board_id`, `group_id`, and `permission`. Value of `permission` is set by either 0(accessible), 1(readable), 2(commentable), 3(writable).

### Problem

Now, this is the problem:

If a user entered typical board named `notice` (`http://example.com/board/notice/`), for example, server must check user's permission. Or, on the main page, user can see preview of boards that user can access, and in this case, server should know **the list of boards that given user can see**.

To deal with above two cases, I want to make a method, `has_permission(self, user, board, permission)` and `get_permitted_user_list(self, user, permission)`.

Then, where these two methods should be in? In `model` or in `view`?

### Case 1) Implementation in Model

Permission is a relation between `Board` and `Group`, not `User`. Dealing with `QuerySet` is just can be done within `Board` objects. It is difficult to me getting a relation between `Board` and `User` from a relation between `Board` and `Group`.

I checked `ModelManager` out, but I don't have any idea how can I solve this problem by using a manager.

### Case 2) Implementation in View

There are 2 simple problems: 1) These methods are widely used, and implementation in a typical view seems to be **not structful**, or in other words, to obey the philosophy of `Django` or `Python`. 2) In all respects, these methods are for `Models` since they are dealing with relations between models. So I think it should be model layer.

Moreover, if implementation in view is a standard, then why there is `ModelManager` in `Model` layer?

### Summary (Fine to forget about all of above discussions)

**`Django` is `MVT`. But a `data` is in everywhere.**

Methods (that deals with data) in `Model` can be called in `View`. Even in `Template` without parameter!

Of course, this method is can be placed in `View`.

**What is the basic standard of difference between roles of M, V, T?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to have a `available_for(user)` method in the `BoardManager` or the `BoardQuerySet` (depending on which one you decide to be the base for development, each can be automatically configured/generated from the other).

You will be able to chain it with other manager methods, so filtering, finding etc will work and you'll be able to use the views' default behaviour for `Board.DoesNotExist` exceptions.

```
Board.objects.published().recent().available_for(user).filter(name=name)[:1].get()
```